# Python: obtencion de datos de un archivo de texto con metodo startswith

Tags: python-3.x

estoy escribiendo un script donde le pido al usuario ingresar un archivo con muchos datos y cree un archivo nuevo con los datos que el necesite. Pero tengo un error que no se como solucionarlo(estoy aprendiendo a programar con Python), al crear el archivo me deja solo el ultimo dato obtenido en ves de todos los datos, este es mi código:

```
NA = input("introduce el nombre del archivo con extensión txt: ")
ARCH = open(NA)
pregunt = input("desa crear un archivo nuevo? si, no: ")
if pregunt == "si":
    NAME = input("que nombre desea ponerle?: ")
    DAT = input("que datos desea obtener: ")
    for AD in ARCH:
        if AD.startswith(DAT):
            ADR = AD
            DEA = [ADR]
            DEA.append(ADR)
            AR = open(NAME, "w")
            AR.write(DEA)
            AR.close()
else:
   DAT = input("que datos desea obtener")
   for ADR in ARCH:
       if ADR.startswith(DAT):
                ADR = AD
                DEA = [ADR]
                DEA.append(ADR)
                AR = open(AA, "w")
                AR.write(DEA)
                AR.close()
```

Comment: Bienvenido @indroic a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Haciendo una lectura rápida del código, dentro del loop `for` se coloca `DEA = [ADR]`, esto hace que sobreescribas la lista `DEA` en cada iteración. Puedes definir `DEA = []` fuera del loop `for` y eliminar `DEA = [ADR]` del código

Comment: @HubertRonald ahora tengo un error de tipo que es este TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list, lo podre solucionar convirtiendo la lista de datos obtenidos a tipo str?

Comment: Exacto, así se solucionaría!

Comment: @HubertRonald sigo en las miasmas, el código solo me deja escrito el ultimo dato obtenido y no todos, como se solucionaría? hice lo que me dijiste en el comentario

Comment: cuando lo imprimo es la consola usando print() me muestra todos los datos que obtiene la lista pero al usarlo para que me los deje en el archivo de texto solo me deja el ultimo